# How do I use ContentResolver to read data from another app's exported ContentProvider on Android 11?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have an app that includes an exported ContentProvider in the Android manifest file

```xml
        <provider
            android:authorities="my.content.Provider"
            android:name="my.content.Provider"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="ExportedContentProvider"/>
```

The implementation of this provider looks as follows:

```kt
package my.content

// imports excluded for brevity

class Provider : ContentProvider() {
    override fun query(
        uri: Uri, p: Array<out String>?, s: String?, sa: Array<out String>?, so: String?
    ): Cursor {
        return MatrixCursor(arrayOf("_id", "data")).apply {
            newRow()
                .add("_id", "1")
                .add("data", "data from the provider")
        }
    }

    override fun getType(uri: Uri) = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.my.content.Providers.data"
    override fun insert(uri: Uri, values: ContentValues?): Uri? = null
    override fun delete(uri: Uri, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<out String>?) = 0
    override fun update(uri: Uri, v: ContentValues?, s: String?, sa: Array<out String>?) = 0
    override fun onCreate() = true
}
```

I can query this provider just fine with adb:

```sh
$ adb shell content query --uri content://my.content.Provider
Row: 0 _id=1, data=data from the provider
```

However I am not able to query it from another app when running on Android 11. I'm trying to follow the Android Developers documentation for [content providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics#Query), but without success. Code from the main activity of my other app where I'm trying to query the content provider:

```kt
val cursor = contentResolver.query(
    Uri.parse("content://my.content.Provider/data"),
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
)
cursor?.apply {
    val dataIndex = getColumnIndex("data")
    while (moveToNext()) {
        println("Data retrieved: ${getString(dataIndex)}")
    }
    close()
}
```

When I run this all I get is an error message printed in logcat: `E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for my.content.Provider`.

Since it's working with adb but not with my content resolver app I assume it's something wrong with the content resolver app, but I can't figure out what. In case it matters, both the content resolver and content provider apps have min sdk level 24 and target/compile sdk version 30.

Comment: What happens if you use the same `Uri` in your client code as you do in the `adb` command? In your question, you are using different `Uri` values (`content://my.content.Provider` in `adb`, `content://my.content.Provider/data` in Kotlin).

Comment: Also, what version of Android are you running on? If it is Android 11+, try adding a `<queries>` element to your manifest to identify the package of the app with the provider.

Comment: Yes, I'm running on Android and adding a <queries> element with a `<provider android:authorities="my.content.Provider" />` child to my content resolver app made it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While most of what is discussed regarding the [package visibility rules](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) surround activities, it is also required for binding to services and, apparently, for interacting with content providers.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit on the accepted answer by CommonsWare, the observed problem is due to new privacy protecting features introduced in Android 11 as described in the [Package visibility in Android 11](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9) blog post.

When targeting and running on Android 11 or newer a [<queries> element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element) needs to be added to the manifest of the app that want to interact with other apps in various ways, including using content providers. The [package visibility documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) indicates that Google Play may analyze the manifest file and the use of the `<queries>` element and the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission in order to detect apps that may access personal and sensitive user data in a non-policy compliant way.

> Also, filtered package visibility helps app stores like Google Play assess the privacy and security that your app provides for users. For example, Google Play considers the list of installed apps to be personal and sensitive user data.

So in the case of using content providers in another app on Android 11, the content resolver app that want to access the content provider data needs to update the manifest file with a `<queries>` element. It should include one `<provider>` child that specifies the authority of the content provider it intends to query:

```xml
    <queries>
        <provider android:authorities="my.content.Provider" />
    </queries>
```

Comment: This is exactly what was happening to me. Thank you.